# PHP get keys in nested array using array_keys( )

Tags: php, arrays

I have a $results array produced from a query and I would like to output a table in html. I would like the header to be "id", "length" and "sample_id". Since the header changes every time, so I used

```
$keys = array_keys($results[0]);
```

I got "array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array" error. If the nested part is not an array, how should I get the keys?

```
array:59 [▼
  0 => {#160 ▼
    +"id": 204
    +"length": 233
    +"sample_id": "ad3"
  }
  1 => {#161 ▼
    +"id": 205
    +"length": 733.5
    +"sample_id": "bt7r"
  }
  2 => {#162 ▶}
  3 => {#163 ▶}
  4 => {#164 ▶}
  5 => {#165 ▶}
```

Comment: Your array seems to contain objects, not arrays.

Comment: change whatever datatype that is to array->get array key-> done??

Comment: `$keys = get_object_vars( $results[0] );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `$results` is actually an array of objects.

I don't know how you got the array, but one can usually choose how to return the objects.

If you're using `PDO`, one can use the method `$statement->fetchAll();`.

One can also get all the "keys" by using the [`get_object_vars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) method to get them:

```
$keys = array_keys(get_object_vars($results[0]));
```

Comment: I used Laravel Query Builder. The array was generated by : $query->get();